# GeoServer flips the WMS v1.3.0 image when applying a heatmap style on a layer with a CRS EPSG:4326

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I was trying to apply the following heatmap style to an unprojected layer (EPSG:4326) in GeoServer.

```
*{
  
  transform: vec:Heatmap(weightAttr:1, radiusPixels:40
    
    , pixelsPerCell:5, 
    
    outputBBOX:env('wms_bbox'), outputWidth:env('wms_width'), outputHeight:env('wms_height'));
  
  raster-channels: auto;
  raster-color-map-type: ramp;
  raster-color-map:color-map-entry(#008000, 0.005,0)
                   color-map-entry(#4B53BC, 0.05, 0.3)
                   color-map-entry(#003348, 0.1, 0.4)
                   color-map-entry(#0099EE, 0.2, 0.5)
                   color-map-entry(#D51606, 0.4, 0.6)
                   color-map-entry(#FF9C33, 0.6, 0.7)
                   color-map-entry(#FFCD42, 0.7, 0.8);
  
}
```

The image displays correct when using WMS v1.1.1 but on v1.3.0, the WMS image gets flipped.

I have replicated the behavior on a default GeoServer layer: Manhattan (NY) points of interest.

### Points:

[image: default style]

### WMS v1.1.1:

[image]

### WMS v1.3.0

[image]

---

However, projected layers such as `sf:bugsites` seems to display correctly.

I believe this is not intended behavior but that the best solution for now is to work with projected data or stick with WMS v 1.1.1?

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behaviour, and is required for WMS 1.3.0. Its documented as https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/basics.html#axis-ordering

I would stick with WMS 1.1 unless you need something in 1.3.0. Using a different projection or adapting to WMS 1.3.0 are also valid solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the link and I was aware of the bbox changes but now I know why. Although I'm still trying to wrap my mind around why the default point style displays the points in the correct locations in both 1.1.1 and 1.3.0 but the image gets flipped when applying the heatmap style. Is it because it is a transformation style and somehow performs the transformation on latitude/longitude although the point geometry was built using longitude/latitude ?

Comment: It would be odd if it was intended, rather it is something that has not been tested. However, I could not find with https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/search?q=heatmap where the error happens.